# How can I copy data from one DB to another oracle DB?

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle12c

I want to update a column of a table. But the required Data is available in another oracle DB.Which is the best way to copy data from remote DB to my DB.

Should I go with Java program or can I achieve it in PL/SQL itself?

Comment: Create a database link to the remove database and then use an UPDATE statement to update the data in the local database. Plain SQL should be able to do the job.

Comment: DB link should do fine if it's a one-off task. But consider ETL tools if you plan on doing it often enough.

Comment: This really depends on multiple factors!  Ask your DBA if you have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood the question, you need to set the value of a column with a value extracted from another table of another DB. The two DBs have different structure.

In this case you can do it with just SQL and a database link.

Here's how to create an Oracle database link: [Oracle documentation for database links](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm)

Then you can write a query like following:

```
UPDATE local_table
SET local_column = (SELECT remote_column FROM remote_table@remote_db WHERE ...)
WHERE ...
```